# Error creating jsf components dynamically using Tomcat 5.0

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, tomcat5

I have created an application which build a grid or a matrix of elements dinamycally.  When I try to navigate to another page I get an error:

This is the code:

```
private HtmlInputText createCelda(String vValue, String vStyle, 
String vTitle, String vId, boolean vscript, boolean isreadonly) { 

// private Application application; 

// FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 

// application = fc.getApplication(); 

// private HtmlInputText ccelda; 



ccelda = new HtmlInputText(); 

ccelda = (HtmlInputText) application 
.createComponent(HtmlInputText.COMPONENT_TYPE); 

ValueExpression ve = application.getExpressionFactory() 
.createValueExpression(fc.getELContext(), vValue, String.class); 

//  ValueExpression ve = application.getExpressionFactory() 
//  .createValueExpression(fc.getELContext(), vValue, Integer.class); 

ccelda.setValueExpression("value", ve); 

ccelda.setStyleClass(vStyle); 

ccelda.setTitle(vTitle); 

ccelda.setId(vId); 

ccelda.setReadonly(isreadonly); 

if (vscript != false) { 

ccelda.setOnkeydown(";return checkGrid(event, this.id);"); 

ccelda.setOnchange(";return changeValue(this.id);"); 

ccelda.setOnclick("this.select()"); 

} 
return ccelda; 
}
```

CODE to create a row of cells with the data from the bean

```
public UIComponent createPanelPrincipal(int nx, int ny, UIComponent panel) { 

panelCeldas = createPanel(nx, "nacionI"); 

for (int i = 1; i < nx + 1; i++) { 

String snx = i > 9 ? String.valueOf(i) : "0" + String.valueOf(i); 

ncelda = createCelda("#{myBean.totalI[" + (i - 1) + "]}", 
celdaNacionIStyle, "I" + snx, "I" + snx, true, false); 

panelCeldas.getChildren().add(ncelda); 

} 
panel.getChildren().add(panelCeldas); 

return panel; 

}
```

This code WORKS PERFECT in tomcat 6.0.18

but in Tomcat 5.0 I get the next error:

```
10-nov-2010 14:56:24 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase execute 
INFO: WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed. 
sourceId=form_composition:I15[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(form_composition:I15: An error occurred when processing your submitted information.), detail=(form_composition:I15: An error occurred when processing your submitted information.)]
```

The line which produce the error is:

```
ValueExpression ve = application.getExpressionFactory() 
.createValueExpression(fc.getELContext(), vValue, String.class);
```

If I put just ccelda.setValue(myValue), works great, but I need to get the value from the bean, that the reason I use the ValueExpression.

I can't see a way to debug this. If anyone is interested I have a stand-alone project to see how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Unified EL ([`ValueExpression`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/el/ValueExpression.html) and consorts) was introduced in JSP 2.1 (note the "Since" note at the bottom of the introductory text in javadoc).

Tomcat 6.x is a Servlet 2.5/JSP 2.1 container, so it supports it.

Tomcat 5.0 is however a Servlet 2.3/JSP 1.2 container, so it doesn't support it. Your best bet is using the (as of JSF 1.2 deprecated) [`ValueBinding`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/el/ValueBinding.html) and friends. Actually, for Servlet 2.3/JSP 1.2 you really have to write all your JSF code as at highest JSF version 1.1, not as 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment.

I have used ValueBinding and friends and the result is the same.

I don't know where exactly the error happens.

I have added a jsf lifecycle as you have in blogspot.

Every phase if fired until phase 6.

Here is it:

```
START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
START PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
END PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
START PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
END PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
START PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
END PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
20-nov-2010 20:00:01 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase execute
INFO: WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=main:I10[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(java.lang.ClassCastException), detail=(java.lang.ClassCastException)]
END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
```

If you or anybody want to take a look this is the link to download:
https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B5-kdDLa5NdMMDYxOGQ2MWMtMWMwNS00MDFlLTkxMWQtM2EzYmZkZDgyMTgy&hl=en

Take a look at Grid.java

Thanks

Updated:

Finally it works,

I have used valueBinding, curiosly I had used before, but I left the libraries for jsf1.2. Now I have eliminated this libraries from the lib's folder and it works. With the other code I had the posibility to specify the type of the value (String, Integer, etc..). Now with ValueBinding it take the value  by default, in my case Integer. I don't know why.  I suppose because Integer is the type of the bean.

Anyway, thanks